# POSIX UDP socket not binding to correct IP

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm in the process of writing a project for college involving writing a chat client and server using POSIX sockets and C++.

The clients are supposed to converse with each other using P2P, such as each client has his own open UDP socket through which he sends and recieves messages from/to other clients.

My problem is 2-fold:

1. My UDPSocket class constructor seems to be ignoring the port number completely, binding to port 65535 regardless of the parameter.
2. The port is binding to IP 255.255.255.255 rather than my own IP (10.0.0.3), or at least that's what i get when I call getpeername.

To the best of my knowledge passing INADDR_ANY should bind to my local address, and passing port number 0 should make the OS choose a free port, what am I doing wrong?

This is the constructor of my UDPSocket class:

```
UDPSocket::UDPSocket(int port){
socket_fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

// clear the s_in struct
bzero((char *) &in, sizeof(in));  /* They say you must do this    */

//sets the sin address
in.sin_family = (short)AF_INET;
in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    /* WILDCARD */
in.sin_port = htons((u_short)port);

fsize = sizeof(from);

//bind the socket on the specified address
if(bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&in, sizeof(in))<0){
    perror ("Error naming channel");
}
}
```

This is the initialization:

```
m_Socket = new UDPSocket(0);
```

And this is the method I use to retrieve the binded address: (UDPSocket inherits Socket)

```
std::string Socket::GetSocketAddress()
{
    struct sockaddr_in  addr;
    int len = sizeof(addr);
    getpeername(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, (socklen_t*)&len);

    char ipAddressBuffer[50];
    memset(ipAddressBuffer, 0, sizeof(ipAddressBuffer));
    sprintf(ipAddressBuffer, "%s:%d", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));

    return ipAddressBuffer;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Avi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `getpeername` , which gives you the remote address of a connected socket. If you check the return value of getpeername(), it should indicate failure.

- You need to use [getsockname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html)() instead of getpeername() to get the address of your local socket
- You need to check that getsockname() succeeds.

Note that your socket is bound to the special 0.0.0.0 address, which means "all local interfaces", so that's what getsockname() will also return.

Comment: Thanks for the (VERY) quick response, although now I'm facing what you seem to have predicted - the address is 0.0.0.0 rather than my own address (10.0.0.3 in this specific case). How do I bind to my local IP address?

Comment: Do you need to ? Binding to 0.0.0.0 will allow you to send and receive packets to/from anywhere.

Comment: How will it work? Say I have my server and 2 clients A and B on 2 different PCs, if I give client A client B's address which is "0.0.0.0:3456" will he be able to send messages to that address and reach client B?

Comment: That means you actually need something else, you want to send your local address to one of your peers. There isn't a single API to find "your IP address" since most systems can have many IP addresses. You can A) call connect() on your socket with the IP address of the one you want to send packets to, After you've called connect(), getsockname() will return the IP address that will be used as the source address when sending packets on that socket. (However once you call connect() that socket can only send packets to the one you connect() to

Comment: Or B), call getifaddrs() and loop through all your addresses and pick one you want. e.g. you could pass in "eth0" to your program and use getifaddrs() to find the IPv4 address of "eth0".

Comment: binding to `INADDR_ANY` mean "accept packets addressed to any address that makes it to this machine."  That means you'll receive packets sent to your address, the loopback address and the broadcast address at the very least.  In order to send packets to another machine, you just need to know an address that will route the packet to that machine (assuming it too is bound to INADDR_ANY).  Once you receive a packet from another peer with `recvfrom`, you'll know an address you can send to that will get back to that peer, so you just have the problem of sending the first packet.

Comment: @nos: with a UDP peer-to-peer setup you generally do NOT want to call connect, since that limits you to a single peer.  Instead you use `sendto`/`recvfrom` on an unconnected socket, allowing you to send messages to any peer and receive from any peer with per-packet souce address.  Once you have your peer addresses from the packets you've received, you can send to any of them -- the only tricky part is bootstrapping the first packet, which generally requires either an explicit address config, or sending broadcast packets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, using getifaddrs and finding my local "eth0" address seems to do the trick, you've been amazingly helpful and saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the more general question "How to set up peer-to-peer communications with UDP":

With UDP sockets, while you can use `connect`, you generally don't want to, as that restricts you to a single peer per socket.  Instead, you want to use a single unconnected UDP socket in each peer with the `sendto` and `recvfrom` system calls to send and receive packets with a different address for each packet.

The `sendto` function takes a packet and a peer address to send it to, while the `recvfrom` function returns a packet and the peer address it came from.  With a single socket, there's no need to multiplexing with `select` or `poll` -- you just call `recvfrom` to get the next packet from any source.  When you get a packet, you also get the peer address to send packets (back) to.

On startup, your peer will create a single socket and bind it to `INADDR_ANY` (allowing it to receive packets on any interface or broadcast address on the machine) and either the specific port assigned to you program or port 0 (allowing the OS to pick any unused port).  In the latter case, you'll need to use `getsockname` to get the port and report it to the user.  Once the socket is set up, the peer program can `sendto` any peer it knows about, or `recvfrom` any peer at all (including those it does not yet know about).

So the only tricky part is bootstrapping -- getting the first packet(s) flowing so that peers can recieve them and figure out their peer addresses to talk to.  One method is specifying peer addresses on the command line when you start each peer.  You'll start the first one with no arguments (as it has no peers -- yet).  It will just recvfrom (after socket setup) to get packets from peers.  Start the second with the address of the first as an argument.  It sends a packet (or several) to the first peer, which will then know about the new peer as soon as it gets the first packet.  Now start a third client with the addresses of the first two on the command line...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it appears to fit the more general case, although in my specific case not so much.